# Can I upgrade my MacBook Pro which has Leopard Mac OS X 10.5.8 to Snow Leopard 10.6.2?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, macbook, upgrade, osx-leopard

I have a MacBook Pro which has Leopard Mac OS X 10.5.8 and i want to upgrade this to Snow Leopard 10.6.2. Is it possible? If yes then give me some guidelines.

Comment: "iphone" is not an appropriate tag for this question.

Comment: The one caveat I would add is "Don't pay too much"! ;-) I'm not sure what the best price currently is, but you can get a retail, 1 system 10.6.3 install DVD from http://eshop.macsales.com/item/Apple/MC573ZA/ for around $31 when shipped USPS. I suggest trying to get a version of the install DVD with includes as many "updates" as possible. It may make your install smoother and will save time by not having to download as large an update later.

Answer (score 3):

This really isn't the right forum for a question of this sort our sister site superuser.com would be. That said this is very easy; just buy 10.6 from Apple, backup your system, boot from the disk, follow the installation instructions then update your system once it's installed - it's that easy.

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple here are the required specs.

- Mac computer with an Intel processor
- 1GB of memory
- 5GB of available disk space DVD drive for installation
- QuickTime H.264 hardware acceleration requires a Mac with an NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, GeForce 320M, or GeForce GT 330M graphics processor.
- Developer tools require 1GB of memory and an additional 3GB of available disk space.
- OpenCL requires one of the following graphics cards or graphics processors: NVIDIA GeForce 320M, GeForce GT 330M, GeForce 9400M, GeForce 9600M GT, GeForce 8600M GT, GeForce GT 120, GeForce GT 130, GeForce GTX 285, GeForce 8800 GT, GeForce 8800 GS, Quadro FX 4800, Quadro FX5600, ATI Radeon HD 4670, ATI Radeon HD 4850, Radeon HD 4870
- 64-bit support requires a Mac with a 64-bit processor.
- Grand Central Dispatch requires a Mac with a multicore processor.